# how to get preferred array pushed in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am receiving data in object form. that object contains properties in which three keys are holding array values. I want to push concat those three array into one master `Array`. But should be in preferred sequence. Like

```
var obj = {'type':['a','b'],'power':[500,700],'make':['2012','2015']}
oneArray(obj,'make','type','power')
```

The master `Array` should have first 'make', 'type' and then 'power' keys `Array` from object. Right now it is coming in order which is given in `obj`
[Fidde](http://jsfiddle.net/6gwg4n0u/)

```
var obj = {'type':['a','b'],'power':[500,700],'make':['2012','2015']}

var oneArray = function (obj,first,second,third){
var newObj = obj;
var list = [];
for(var key in newObj){
 if (newObj[key] instanceof Array) {
          if (!list) {
            list = newObj[key];
          }
          else {
            list = list.concat(newObj[key]);
          }

        }
}
newObj['all'] = list;
return newObj
}

console.log(oneArray(obj,'make','type','power'))
```

Comment: `return { all: obj.make.concat(obj.type).concat(obj.power) }` ...!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I have understood your question, but try this...
This onArray() function takes parameters that indicating priorities in orderly manner but first parameter.

```
var obj = {'type':['a','b'],'power':[500,700],'make':['2012','2015']}

var oneArray = function(obj) {
    var newObj = obj;
    var list = [];
    var priorityList = arguments;

    for( var i = 1 ; i < priorityList.length ; i++ ) {
        if( newObj[ priorityList[i] ] instanceof Array ) {
            for( var key in newObj[ priorityList[i] ] ) {
                list.push( newObj[ priorityList[i] ][ key ] );
            }
        }
    }

    newObj['all'] = list;
    return newObj;
}

console.log(oneArray(obj,'make','type','power'));
```

Comment: This code is a kind of a sample.. You should add some validation logic into it, if you want to use this on production environment...